# An emitter follower to isolate MCU from load?

Tags: bjt, interface, emitter-follower

I am trying to drive an LED strip (10 LEDs) from the output of an ESP8266 GPIO pin. I measured the short circuit current from the GPIO and got around 40 mA. My question: Is it recommended to include an emitter follower stage to isolate my ESP8266 and my load (LED strip)? I don't want my load to draw a large current from the MCU pin which could alter the logic level.

A crude circuit is shown below (component values are not as per calculation)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8dgYH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You do it as simple as this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffOwhe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 1kΩ resistor at the base of the transistor feeds about 2mA@3.3V into the small signal NPN transistor, that's enough to saturate it for a collector current of up to 100mA. If you need more than that, consider a darlington NPN instead. VLED may be up to 50V or so, whatever your small signal NPN offers.